# How to deploy Openfire server

Tags: java, openfire

I have just started using Openfire. I have created a sample plugin and it works in my IDE. I want to deploy this server on a machine but don't know how.
The read me explains how i can start it in IDE. I know how a war/jar file is deployed. but I don't know how to deploy Openfire. It does not seems to have a jar. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build Openfire by issuing the following command in the root of the source code:

`mvn clean package`

After you do this, a directory will be created that holds a fully functional Openfire server. You can find it in `distribution/target/distribution-base`

That folder holds a fully functional copy of your build. You can copy it elsewhere, and run Openfire from there.

Note that the folder does not include installers. Those are (mostly) generated by a proprietary bit of software (Install4J). It's configuration is part of the source tree, but to make use of it, you'll have to obtain a copy of the Install4J application.